# How to restrict or grant access to Discord bots using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I´ve recently made an economy bot that should make users buy access to other bots we have in the server (memes bots, music bots...). The idea is that if you don´t buy the access, you won´t be able to use the bot, but once you buy it, you will be able to use it. Is there any way I can restrict or grant access to Discord bots using Discord.js? Thanks!

I haven´t tried anything yet since I have no idea of what to do.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "buy")) {
  if (args[0] == "bot") {
    let balance = eco.FetchBalance(message.author.id).then((result) => {
      if (result.balance >= 1500) {
        eco.SubstractFromBalance(message.author.id, 1500);

        message.channel.send("Bought bot access");

        // Grant bot access
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Howdy, and welcome to stack overflow. Your question seems a little too broad fro this forum. Also I doubt charging for a discord bot is complies with Discord terms of service. If you have a specific question relating to the API or JS try modifying your question to be more specific to that.

Comment: @danielson317 I agree with what you are saying, however selling Discord bots (restricting access as a part of a premium program) is not against ToS. But you did not know this so I am just informing you! (Also, there does not seem to be any actual monetary transactions, this appears to be all virtual currency as a sort of economy system)

Comment: Just wanting to clarify, is the idea that the bot is already on the server and only users that have "bought access" have permissions to execute the commands? If so, you could assign roles to the users and before executing a command you could check that the user has a specified role

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could do it several ways, but for me the most reasonable is with prefix.
Let's imagine you have dynobot and his prefix is `#`. 
I'm using [quick.db](https://quickdb.js.org/) as `db`

```
(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "buy")) {
  let access = await db.fetch(`access_${message.author.id}`);
  if (args[0] == "botDyno") {
if(db.has(`access_${message.author.id}.dynobot`)) return message.reply("You already have that access");
 var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "AccessToDynoBot");
    let balance = eco.FetchBalance(message.author.id).then((result) => {
      if (result.balance >= 1500) {
        eco.SubstractFromBalance(message.author.id, 1500);
        if(!access){
        message.member.addRole(role);
        db.set(`access_${message.author.id}`, {dynobot: 'yes'})
        }
        else{
        message.member.addRole(role);
        db.push(`access_${message.author.id}`, {dynobot: 'yes'})
        }
        message.channel.send("Bought bot access");
      }
    }
  }
```

And then on event `message` you need to verify if someone has access

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
if(message.content.startsWith("#") && !db.has(`access_${message.author.id}.dynobot`){
return message.reply("Sorry, but you need to buy access")
}
if(message.content.startsWith("!!") && !db.has(`access_${message.author.id}.rythmbot`){
return message.reply("Sorry, but you need to buy access")
}
}
```

Let's imagine you want to sell another bot access but with prefix !!

```
(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "buy")) {
  let access = await db.fetch(`access_${message.author.id}`); 
  if (args[0] == "botRythm") {
  var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "AccessToRythmBot");
  if(db.has(`access_${message.author.id}.rythmbot`)) return message.reply("You already have that access");
    let balance = eco.FetchBalance(message.author.id).then((result) => {
      if (result.balance >= 1500) {
        eco.SubstractFromBalance(message.author.id, 1500);
        if(!access){
        message.member.addRole(role);
        db.set(`access_${message.author.id}`, {rythmbot: 'yes'})
        }
        else{
        message.member.addRole(role);
        db.push(`access_${message.author.id}`, {rythmbot: 'yes'})
        }
        message.channel.send("Bought bot access");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It will only tell the User that he is not allowed to use that bot, but there is no Way to stop the User from using them.

Answer (score 0):

If the other bots are not made by you, my best suggestion is lock that bot to only be usable in a specific channel, then have your economy bot unlock said channel for the user that purchased the bot.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it would be easier to use the bots' "allowed roles" function then allow the users to buy said roles

Comment: Does this answer the question?